# Visualizing data with uneven distribution as 2D color plot - Likert scale (MatLab)

Tags: matlab, histogram, data-visualization, scatter-plot

(I've also posted this at Cross Validated, but I was told that I could not seek direct MatLab advice, so now I try here)

I am using MatLab and PR Tools to visualize my data, but I have a problem with how my data is distributed.

Long story short:
I've created a 2D platforming game where the acceleration and deceleration time for the player avatar change (i.e., how long time it takes before player reaches maximum horizontal velocity). The time values can either be fast [0-240 ms] or slow [241-1500 ms]. The numbers are chosen randomly within these two intervals, so that some players will have [acceleration;deceleration] times like [10 ms;700 ms], [1400 ms;30 ms], [100 ms; 241 ms], etc.

As you can see, the intervals are not of equal size, which means my sampling distribution is uneven, as shown in this figure (there are much more samples in the [1-240 ms] range.

[image: Overall distribution]

My participants rated the feeling of controlling the avatar with these acceleration/deceleration times. They rated how "twitchy", "fluid", "floaty", "responsive", etc. that the game felt. They did this with a 7-point Likert scale (1 = "not at all"; 7 = "a lot").

Here is an example of a scatter plot I made:

[image: Scatter plot of Twitchy and Fluid]

The problem is that it is difficult to look for clusters due to the uneven distribution of the acceleration/deceleration times.

My teacher then suggested:

> Now that I've seen the sampling pattern in Figure 10, I'm less convinced that these scatterplots are useful because it is very hard to interpret whether an increased number of points in the regions < 0.2 seconds is due to the sampling pattern or some real effect.
>
> An alternative would be a 2D color histogram (see [http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~ikarpov/tourney2011/rr/tourney-run-RR-sorted.png](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Eikarpov/tourney2011/rr/tourney-run-RR-sorted.png)) that shows the deviation from the number of a certain rating in each block (e.g. blocks of size 0.24x0.24) compared to the number of ratings you would expect in each block if the probability of each rating was uniform for all samples. In this way, different sampling density would not directly bias the numbers.

I am unsure how to approach this, since I am still relatively new to the world of statistics. Do I need to make a color matrix plot --- and how?

How would you do that in MatLab (+ PR Tools)?

Right now, I use *scatterdui(my_data)* in MatLab with PR Tools to make the scatter plots.

The classes are Likert ratings 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please do not post the same question on multiple SE sites. If you think (or someone told you) it fits better somewhere else, you can ask a moderator to migrate it (via "flag" / "in need of moderator attention").

Comment: Regarding your question, have a look at [hist3d](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/hist3.html).

Comment: Besides that, I think you have to decide which *exact question* you want to answer. This should lead (more or less) naturally to the right visualization and/or statistical tools.